# C# youtube video not playing anymore

Tags: c#, video

Hello I have an application that used to allow me to watch videos from youtube, but now the screen is completely black, I cannot view videos. I am using `axmediaplayer` and here is my code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // play video in embedded media player
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "http://www.youtube.com/v/Of9JCZ6zraQ";
    }
```

Is it a change made on youtube or does any one know alternatives? it used to work before but not it is not working any more. does any one know what the problem is please?

Comment: I have the same problem with TEmbeddedWB in Delphi. It used to work all the time, but from some time it does not work anymore!